# Load images into a Gallery after Activity's view is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-asynctask, android-gallery

I'm developing an Android 3.1 tablet application.

I need to load and show some images which are stored in local disk. Know UI gets freeze while images are loading and are shown on a gallery and I wondering if there another way to show ui, and when ui is shown, show a `ProgressDialog` and then start loading from disk and showing every image.

I know how to start and `Asyntask` but I don't know how to do something after ui is show.

I put `task.execute()` on `OnCreate` and on `OnResume` and I see UI freeze.

**How can I execute a task after UI is shown?**

If you need to take a look to code, please check [Gallery images still load very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046076/gallery-images-still-load-very-slow) and [ClassCastException: AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to Gallery$LayoutParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044353/classcastexception-abslistviewlayoutparams-cannot-be-cast-to-gallerylayoutpar) questions.

Comment: To understand beter, you want a gallery with images loaded from internal memory? are they already downloaded? why do you need asynctask? just for showing them? By the way, gallery is deprecated, why don't use horizontalScroolView or viewpager?

Comment: No, I have an `ArrayList<String>` with images' paths. I will load this images from local disk and they are on local disk. I new on Android development and I didn't know Gallery is deprecated.

Comment: what do you mean by local disk? I thought you have them on the phone's memory or card?

Comment: Oh, sorry. They are on SD Card.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have an Activity with your Gallery (or whatever you decide to use) and a Gallery Adapter. In the `getView()` of the adapter you should load an image (`getView()` is gallery for every gallery object).
For loading you should have a method like this:

```
public static Bitmap loadFromPath(String file_path) {
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inDither = false; // disable dithering
   options.inScaled = false; // do not scale bitmap when loading; scale later
   options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
   Bitmap backgroundBitmap = null;
    try {
         backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path, options);
     } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return backgroundBitmap;
```

}

And this returned bitmap you can use to set the imageView's source in `getView()`.
If you have issues, let me know!